# Sophos issue with twitimg

Tags: sophos

We're using virtual sophos utm for our hospitality company, as a guest network firewall. Some users reported that they are not able to use twitter when connected our wi-fi network. Investigated that twitter app is working, fetching the tweets with no issue but media files like videos, pictures, twitter profile pictures does not displaying. We have two network zones

1. WAN
2. Guest

and a firewall rule called "live users which has settings as follows;
Source
Source zone : Guest *any* *all the time*
Destination zone : WAN *any* *any*

Identify
Match known users: ticked
Show captive portal to unknown users : ticked
user groups *any*

Web malware and content scanning
Block Google QUIC (Quick UDP Internet Connections) ticked

Intrusion prevention : general policy *with no IPS settings enabled inside*
Web Policy : Guest *anybody* *all web traffic* *allowed* *status:enabled*
enable logging and reporting is enabled

Application Control: 
Guest *social network* category *all the time* *allowed*

it seems that there's no policy that can block these media files coming from to twitter application but they're still getting blocked.

ayn idea about what could be the problem?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sophos UTM

Add the following URLs under Web Protection -> Filtering options -> Exception -> For all requests -> Matching these URLs as

```
^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?twitter\.com/
```

and in Application control allow Twitter app

Answer (score -1):

Reload the Firewall rules on the UTM. Sometimes the rules need to be switched off and back on again to take action.